# disable/enable selectInput and fileInput upon the selection of Advanced checkboxInput

Tags: shiny

I have a Shiny code as like this

```
library(datasets)
ui <-fluidPage(    
titlePanel("Telephones by region"),
sidebarLayout(      
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("region", "Region:", 
              choices=colnames(WorldPhones)), checkboxInput(inputId = "Adv",
                                                            label = strong("Advanced"),
                                                            value = FALSE),fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = FALSE,accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),
  hr(),
  helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("phonePlot")   )))

server <- function(input, output) {

output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({

barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
        main=input$region,
        ylab="Number of Telephones",
        xlab="Year")})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I need to implement following modifications

1. How to disable/enable selectInput and fileInput upon the selection of Advanced checkboxInput. If user choose advanced, the selectInput must be disable (vice versa)
2. How to use if function for fileInput from user input (Asia,Africa….ect one per line )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable/disable the inputs you can use package `shinyjs`.
Something like this should work:

```r
library(datasets)
library(shiny)
ui <-fluidPage(   
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel("Telephones by region"),
    sidebarLayout(      
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                        choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),
            checkboxInput(inputId = "Adv",
                          label = strong("Advanced"),
                          value = FALSE),
            fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      multiple = FALSE,accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),
            hr(),
            helpText("Data from AT&T (1961) The World's Telephones.")),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("phonePlot")   )))

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    observe({
        
        if((input$Adv == TRUE)) {
            shinyjs::disable("region")
            shinyjs::disable("file1")
        } else {
            shinyjs::enable("region")
            shinyjs::enable("file1")
        }
    })
    
    output$phonePlot <- renderPlot({
        
        barplot(WorldPhones[,input$region]*1000, 
                main=input$region,
                ylab="Number of Telephones",
                xlab="Year")})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```